# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements using App store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, distribution, entitlements

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

(0xE8008016).

I have tried all the possibilities but still facing issue.

Answer (score 4):

Delete your Entitlements.plist, and make sure your "Code Signing Entitlements" build setting is blank.  Entitlements.plist is no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Code Signing Identity values under Project  > Build Settings and Targets > Build Settings are correct.